# Remove zero after first space pandas regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = 

number
+123 1234
+123 0123
+123+123 01234
+123 0123 0023
```

I want to remove only 0 only after first space as a new column.
Desired output:

```
number            filtered
+123 1234         +123 1234
+123 0123         +123 123
+123+123 01234    +123+123 1234
+123 0123 0023    +123 123 0023
```

My try is:

```
df['filtered'] = df['number'].replace(r'\s(.)', '', regex=True)
```

But I realized that it is removing first character after space not only zero

---

I am ok even with different approach, not regex only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match from beginning of line up to a zero `0` after the first space, and then replace the match with capture group 1:

```
^(\S*\s)0
```

[Regex demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NIMpEX/1)

In python:

```py
df['filtered'] = df['number'].replace(r'^(\S*\s)0', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
    +123 1234
     +123 123
+123+123 1234
+123 123 0023
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I found that regex is powerful thing. Where I can read about documentation or combinations of this elements to get desired result?

Comment: @Mamed there's a good reference q&a [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) and a good tutorial [here](https://www.regexbuddy.com/tutorial.html) and I highly recommend playing with regexes on sandbox sites such as [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\s0
```

Python

```py
df['filtered'] = df['number'].replace(r'\s0', ' ', regex=True)
```

Comment: Notice that your regex filters out one extra `0` in the bottom row: `initial: +123 0123 0023`, `expected: +123 123 0023`, `yours: +123 123 023`. This happened because you coded to remove any `0` preceded by whitespace in a row.